# Getting data from AD via Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Can someone help?
I'm trying to get data from AD (via PS) in Excel (CSV), but my script put all objects in 1 columns, not in deafferents.

```
class GoodFree {
    static [object[]] Make ([string]$GroupName){
        return (Get-ADGroupMember $GroupName |
        ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                lic = '1123'
                name = $_.Name
                gName = $GroupName
            }
        })
}

[GoodFree]::Make('LV-DPA') | Out-File C:\Users\Downloads\Users.csv
```

Comment: Don;t convert the PS objects to strings. Don;t use `Out-File` - there's an `Export-CSV` command

Answer (score 0):

As Scepticalist mentions in their comment, there's a specific Export-Csv cmdlet for CSV-files.

After the pipe use `Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\Downloads\Users.csv`

Powershell automatically adds type information to CSV-files so you may want to add the `-NoTypeInformation` switch to the above command to skip that.
If you wish to manage the file encoding you can use the `-Encoding` switch to for instance get the file in UTF8.
Powershell uses the Windows-culture to determine the standard delimiter for CSV-files, but you can change that with the `-Delimiter` switch. Add `';'` to use semicolons as delimiters for the file.

Comment: Actually, `Export-Csv` uses the **comma** by default unless you tell it to use something else with for instance `-Delimiter ';'`. There is also a switch called `-UseCUlture` which makes PowerShell use the delimiter as set for the local machine's ListSeparator.